# python: histogram chart of timedelta values

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, timedelta

I have df with ['time_start','time_end'] information with columns datetime type. Adding new column:

```
 df['period'] = df['time_end'] - df['time_start']
```

Then, i would like to understand histogram of 'period' and trying to plot the graph:

```
plt.hist(df['period'], color = 'cyan', edgecolor = 'black', bins = int(180/10))
plt.show()
```

and have the error back:

```
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'less' input 1 from dtype('float64') to dtype('<m8[ns]') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

meanwhile, plt of df['time_start'] works fine.
if i made a change of 'delta' to seconds by:

```
 df['period'] = (df['time_end'] - df['time_start']).dt.seconds
```

it works also fine.

May you please explailn how to analyze timedelta data?

Comment: Can you show what `df.period.head()` looks like? It might be something simple like needing to convert to float first: `(df.time_end - df.time_start).astype(float)`? Without a reproducible example, it's hard for me to be sure

Comment: @MichaelSilverstein here it is:
0   0 days 01:21:20.034990
1   0 days 19:39:04.498480
2   5 days 21:33:43.898156
3   0 days 14:15:47.531027
4   0 days 15:17:58.905265
Name: rent_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

Comment: concerning your code, I'd suggest to use `.total_seconds()`, not only the `.seconds`. Other than that, "*how to analyze timedelta data*" is not really a programming question (= off topic on SO)...

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks!